# Why is it sufficient to consider only generators when counting the number of isomorphisms between groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having difficulties understanding this. It is not a task, I'm just curious as to how this makes sense mathematically.

Consider all the isomorphism's from Z9 to Z6. To answer the question of how many are there, we  can do the following.

We know that 1 generates Z9 and 1^9 = e in Z9. Hence, any element a in Z6 for which a^9=e holds, can act act as a valid mapping. There are 3 such elements in Z6, hence there are 3 isomorphism's between Z9 and Z6.

I know this is the solution, but I'm having difficulties understanding this. Why do we only consider 1? Z9 has other generators. Is it because they can be expressed as a multiple of 1? Also, why do we only consider the generators when we are looking for accurate mappings?

Comment: Because homomorphisms respect group operations, any homomorphism is uniquely determined by how it maps generators, since all other elements can be written as group operations applied to the generators.

Comment: one it is determined what a generator is mapped to, it is determined what any element is mapped to

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Comment: If we consider homomorphisms from Z2xZ2 -> Z4, since the generating set = {(0,1)(1,0)},we have 4 homomorphisms as we can map them both to 2, both to 0, or either to 0 or 2. Is this correct?